# Suppress lineskip in heading without titlesec package in memoir class

Tags: sectioning, memoir

Is there a way to make sections, subsections etc. runin-like without using the titlesec package in the memoir class?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...
\subsection{Subsection title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...
\end{document}
```

The result of the above is something like:

**Section title**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

**Subsection title**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

But I would like:

**Section title** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

**Subsection title** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

... and as mentioned without the titlesec package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to the example below would do it. The sign of the value of the spacing after the header controls whether it is runin or not. (the sign of the spacing above controls indentation or not)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\setaftersecskip{-1em}
\setaftersubsecskip{-1em}
\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...
\subsection{Subsection title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...
\end{document}
```